# vedio frame is closing automatically in open cv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

i am trying to stream a live vedio from cctv camera using open cv but vedio frame is showing and closing immediately. kindly help me out

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

kernel=None
# This is a test video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.18.2277:554/user=admin_password=_channel=4_stream=0.sdp?real_stream.sdp')

while (cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

        # This function will return a boolean variable telling if someone was present or not, it will also draw boxes if it
    # finds someone

    ret = cap.set(3, 200)
    ret = cap.set(4, 300)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # Calculate the Average FPS
    frame_counter += 1
    fps = (frame_counter / (time.time() - start_time))

    # Exit if q is pressed.
    if cv2.waitKey(30) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release Capture and destroy windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What did you find when you tried to debug this code? Is the loop ever entered? At which point does the loop exit? Is it the `if not ret`? Or the `if cv2.waitKey(30) == ord('q')`? Or something else?

Comment: loop is exiting at if not ret

Comment: Then you need to find out why the first return value of `cap.read()` is 0 or `None` or whatever "false" value it is. Or maybe this indicates success? Then using break in this case would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 points to be changed above:

1. you have not imported time library but you have called the current time function in your algorithm.
2. start_time is specified but what will be the start time isn't. If it is the time that the program is executed then please define it.
3. Also you have to first define what is Frame_counter, and cannot directly increment it by 1.

---

```
            import cv2
            #import time function
            import time
            cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            kernel=None
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            #define start_time
            start_time = time.time()
            #frame counter value
            frame_counter = 1
            while (cap.isOpened()):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
                ret = cap.set(3, 200)
                ret = cap.set(4, 300)
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                frame_counter += 1
                fps = (frame_counter / (time.time() - start_time))
                if cv2.waitKey(30) == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Please excuse if there are any mistakes, I am also a beginner.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i have already define and imported the libraries. i have only shown you a specific code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a if and else you can just write cv2.waitKey(1) at the end of your while loop. Hope that fixes the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't hesitate to go a little more deep in detains for answers. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if not ret: break` statement and your code should work properly